# Wordpress custom post type - edit fields

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

We have built a custom post type on Wordpress with many custom fields where users can submit post and later review it under categories and on the homepage.

Now we want to enable users My Account and Edit post page, that is not inside standard Worpdress dashboard.

I have managed to find some plugins but they dont support my needs fully.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simply using  wordpress function   **wp_insert_post()** to manually create posts from front end.

Here is the  sample code:

```
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'My post',
  'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => array(8,39)
);

wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: No, we have done that part. User can insert post on the front end. What I am looking is how to enable user to EDIT post from the fronend..

Comment: ok to edit post from the front end you just need to create  edit button for every post after login and after that when user click on that  button it will open the same value of post in  form from where you can easily update  value in data  base  by update query for that post by  post id